# Avoiding multiple map and filter to compress and filter the array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of object like

```
var someObjects = [
{'label': 'VS', 'value': 1 },
{'label': 'V1', 'value': 2 },
{'label': 'V2', 'value': 3 },
{'label': 'V3', 'value': 4 },
{'label': 'V4', 'value': 5 },
{'label': 'V5', 'value': 6 },
{'label': 'V6', 'value': 7 },
{'label': 'V7', 'value': 8 },
{'label': 'V8', 'value': 9 },
{'label': 'V9', 'value': 10 },
{'label': 'V10', 'value': 11 },
{'label': 'V11', 'value': 12 },
{'label': 'V12', 'value': 20 },
{'label': 'V13', 'value': 15 },
{'label': 'VE', 'value': 13 }
];
```

I need to produce new array like in order

```
[
{'label': 'VS', 'value': 1 },
{'label': 'V1', 'value': 2 },
{'label': 'V2', 'value': 3 },
{'label': 'V3', 'value': 4 },
{'label': 'V4', 'value': 5 },
{'label': 'V5', 'value': 6 },
{'label': 'V6', 'value': 7 },
{'label': 'V7', 'value': 8 },
{'label': 'V8', 'value': 9 },
{'label': 'V9', 'value': 10 },
{'label': 'V10+', 'value': 15 },
{'label': 'VE', 'value': 13 }
];
```

Here I have to find find value for object with max V with number and all other should remain same.

The way I am doing is I am using 
- .filter for <10 || 'S'
- .find for 10
- .find over map to get max value
- .find for 'T'

Seems to complex. Any suggestion?

***Update*** Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0kLdpz9x/) I tried. Still have to do `find`, `map` then `reduce` on the array. Any suggestion to simplify this?

Comment: could you post the actual code that you're trying to improve upon? It's not clear from your description what you're trying to do

Comment: There is no object in first array with `value` 30 but you have that in second array!

Comment: what is `V` and `T`? what is `S`?

Comment: Question is not clear. The logic on why the result is what you need to get is not clear either.

Comment: Just think that reading your question seems more complex too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop over the array and reduce it with a closure of the collecting `ten` object.

```js
var array = [{ label: 'VS', value: 1 }, { label: 'V1', value: 2 }, { label: 'V2', value: 3 }, { label: 'V3', value: 4 }, { label: 'V4', value: 5 }, { label: 'V5', value: 6 }, { label: 'V6', value: 7 }, { label: 'V7', value: 8 }, { label: 'V8', value: 9 }, { label: 'V9', value: 10 }, { label: 'V10', value: 11 }, { label: 'V11', value: 12 }, { label: 'V12', value: 20 }, { label: 'VE', value: 13 }],
    result = array.reduce(function (ten) {
        return function (r, a) {
            var n = +a.label.match(/\d+$/);
            if (n >= 10) {
                if (!ten) {
                    ten = { label: 'V10+', value: 0 };
                    r.push(ten);
                }
                ten.value = Math.max(ten.value, a.value);
            } else {
                r.push(a);
            }
            return r;
        };
    }(), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: close but I still need to find the value of max numeric label. Updated by question with fiddle I tried.